# Linux web server is very slow and using 100% CPU

Tags: linux, performance, webserver

I found out that the CPU on my Linux web server is always on 100%.

Well the web host of mine said that the following processes are responsible for this:

[image]

What could this be? Maybe a virus or a miner? How can I fix the problem? I haven't found anything comparable on Google to this process yet. My web host can't solve this either because they don't know what the exact problem is.

For your information, a month ago I had a miner on my server (kdevtmpfsi). However, it was professionally removed by an IT security specialist.

Comment: Without access to your own server it will be impossible to resolve your problem. (This information is contained within a comment that was erroneously submitted as an answer that has already been deleted)

Answer (score 1):

> a month ago I had a miner on my server (kdevtmpfsi). However, it was professionally removed by an IT security specialist.

It seems possible they might not have done a very professional job. Or you and they did not fully address the vulnerability which was previously exploited.

`./linuxsys` looks suspicious.

See [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/q/100360/52492)

Once a webserver has been compromised you really need to wipe it clean, reinstall and configure the operating system, reinstall your applications and restore data from one of your daily/weekly/monthly backups after verifying they are completely clean.